# How to unit test methods together with its constraint validators (which some should be mocked out)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, cdi, bean-validation

My app has a service layer which is composed by CDI applications scoped beans:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Transactional
public class PostService {
    @Inject private PostRepository postRepo;
    @Inject private UserRepository userRepo;
    @Inject private SectionRepository sectionRepo;
    @Inject private LoggedInUser loggedInUser;

    public PostDto getPost(@PostExists int id){
        Post p = postRepo.findById(id);
        //create post DTO from p
        return post;
    }

    public void delete(@PostExists int id){
        postRepo.remove(postRepo.findById(id));
    }

    public int newPost(@NotBlank @Max(255) String title,
                       @Max(2000) String body,
                       @SectionExists String sectionName){
        User user = userRepo.getByName(loggedInUser.getUsername());
        Section section = sectionRepo.getByName(sectionName);

        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle(title);
        post.setContent(body == null || body.isBlank() ? "" : body);
        post.setAuthor(user);
        post.setSection(section);
        post.setType(TEXT);

        return postRepo.insert(post).getId();
    }

}
```

When a method gets called, an interceptor (in my case `BValInterceptor.class` from Apache BVal) checks if the method contract is respected by checking the annotations and validating the parameters accordingly.

As you can see, there are some custom constraints like `@SectionExists`, `@PostExists` that may hit the database:

```
public class SectionExistsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SectionExists, String> {
    @Inject SectionRepository sectionRepo;

    @Override
    public void initialize(SectionExists constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return (sectionRepo.getByName(value) != null);
    }
}



public class PostExistsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PostExists, Integer> {
    @Inject PostRepository postRepo;

    @Override
    public void initialize(PostExists constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return (postRepo.findById(value) != null);
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to unit test my business methods (`getpost`, `delete`, `newPost`) **together** with its validators. The validators that may hit the database should be mocked (or their dependency should be mocked).

How can I achieve this? How could I make injections (and mock injections) work for validators in unit tests?

Here what I'm using:

- TomEE 8.0.8
- Apache BVal for Bean Validation JSR 303/JSR380 (included in TomEE)
- Apache OpenWebBeans for CDI (included in TomEE)
- JUnit 5
- Mockito

I can use [OpenEJB's ApplicationComposer](https://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/application-composer/) or Arquillian to run an embedded container. However, I've never used Arquillian.

Comment: To test CDI beans, you will find [weld-junit](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit) and [cdi-unit](https://github.com/cdi-unit/cdi-unit) interesting. Together with a mocking framework, like Mockito, you can mock CDI dependencies - I would suggest you mock the repositories. And you *can* test bean validation, as long as you enable the Bean Validation CDI interceptors.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos does cdi-unit support Apache OpenWebBeans? It seems that i can use CDI with OpenEJB's ApplicationComposer (Which supports JUnit 5, so thumbs up for that).

Comment: The only problem is that i **can't** inject mocked repositories inside the validators using the @ Mock annotation. I should maybe try to mess with the ConstraintValidatorFactory and inject the mocks after the creation of the CV, or maybe use the @ Alternative annotation. I'll try it tomorrow and edit the question accordingly if anything new occurs

Comment: I had the impression that cdi-unit supported any CDI implementation, apparently I was wrong. On the other hand, you should be able to test your CDI components in any compliant implementation, so testing in Weld and running in OpenWebBeans is probably safe (but yeah, a bit awkward). The good thing about cdi-unit/weld-junit is that they do not launch a full app server, like Arquillian (or I guess ApplicationComposer), so tests are quite fast. If you decide to go for one of them, I think I have an example of activating Bean Validations that may help.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Ok, i'm definitely gonna try out CDI-Unit. The @ Produces @ Mock annotation really is what i really need (it adds the mocks in cdi context scope).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos in the end i've found a solution that supports OWB (cdimock), thank you for your kind help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went for [this really cool library (cdimock)](https://github.com/ArneLimburg/cdimock) that does exactly what i needed: put the mocks in a custom CDI scope so that the same mock instances can be injected in other beans inside the test case. Such thing can also be achievable with [cdi-unit](https://github.com/cdi-unit/cdi-unit) `@Produces @Mock` annotations (Although i haven't tried it personally since it only supports Weld)

This is my test class' code:

```
@RunWithApplicationComposer(mode = ExtensionMode.PER_EACH)
@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class, CdiMocking.class})
@MockitoSettings(strictness = LENIENT)
@Classes(cdi = true,
         value={PostService.class},
         cdiInterceptors = BValInterceptor.class,
         cdiStereotypes = CdiMock.class)
public class PostServiceTest {

    @Mock SectionRepository sectionRepository;
    @Mock PostRepository postRepository;
    @Mock UserRepository userRepository;
    @Inject PostService service;   

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {}

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {}

    @Test
    public void noSectionFoundNewPost(){
        String sectionName = "idontexist";
        when(sectionRepository.getByName(sectionName)).thenReturn(null);
        assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class,
                () -> service.newPost("title", "body", sectionName));
    }
}
```

In the code i'm using OpenEJB's Application Composer but i can easily switch to any embedded CDI container